# How to update Enterprise Architect Tables using C#

Tags: computer-science, add-in, enterprise-architect

I do not find Repository.Execute (SQL) to update tables in Enterprise Architecture using C# + Ea.Repository
I am using Enterprise Architecture v 10.0

I want to **insert/update**  values into table **t_connector** using  my Add-Ins

```
Repository.SQLQuery(SQL_Query);// for query
```

but there is no functions for update/execute in EA 10.0, how can  I solve this issue in order to insert/update statements in EA Repository

Comment: Try sticking to `Element.Connectors.AddNew` to insert new connectors. As Geert says: `Execute` can well lead to a "model execution" in the sense of death sentence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the **undocumented and unsupported** method `Repository.Execute(SQLString)`

But realize: using `Repository.Execute()` is completely at your own risk. You better know what you are doing.